# Textarea in Rails form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have an HTML form in Rails:

```
<form id="my_form" action="submit">
  Title: <input type="text" name="title"> 
</form>
```

I want to add a new field using a `<textarea>`:

```
Comment: <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Is it okay if put this into the form? How can I access the value that the user fills in?

Comment: Of course it's okay to put a `textarea` input in a form. Are you using the rails [form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)? What is your actual view code?

Comment: @shioyama My actual view code is (more or less) what I posted for the `<form>`. I'm not using Rails form helpers, because these data actually do not go into a database and does not correspond to any model -- instead, they're processed by the controller to show appropriate content for the user. Do you think I should use form helpers?

Comment: You can still use form helpers to create tags, e.g. [`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) etc.

Comment: If I use that, how do I create a `textarea`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you have some good reason not to, you should really use the action view helpers provided by rails.

The [form helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) provide resource-oriented methods which create a form and a scope around a specific model object, but this does not suit your case.

What you want instead is to use to use the generic [form tag helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html), which include generic versions of the form methods not tied to any specific model or record, e.g.: [`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag), [`text_field_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag), [`text_area_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_area_tag), etc. These methods do not require you to pass a record to them or define them in terms of a specific model; you can define arbitrary actions, ids etc., like so:

```
<%= form_tag "submit", :id => "my_form" do -%>
  Title: <%= text_field_tag "title" %>
  Comment: <%= text_area_tag "comment", :rows => 4, :cols => 50 %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end -%>
```

Note that you had no `name` or `id` on your textarea, so I've arbitrarily assigned them the string `"comment"`, which makes sense for the case.

In terms of accessing the value(s) the user enters, you just do it like any other form, i.e. in your controller you just access `params[:title]`, `params[:comment]` etc.

Answer (score 1):

if you use form_tag helper then you can create textarea as follows:

```
      text_area_tag(:comment, nil, :rows => 5, :cols => 15)
```

Your code for form_tag would be as follows:

```
  <% form_tag :action => :submit do %>
  <%= label_tag "Title" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :title %>
  <%= text_area_tag :comment, nil, :rows => 5, :cols => 15 %>
  <%= submit_tag "submit" %>
  <% end %>
```

You should have method called submit in your controller. In that method you can access comment using params. For example comment can be accessed as params[:comment]

For more info see this: [forms_and_tags](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html)

Answer (score 0):

What about using this way when the user presses Title: the box will highlight it gives the user a bit more flexibility.

```
<form id="my_form" action="submit">
<label for="title">Title: </label>
<input type="text" name="title" id="title"> 
</form>
```

Comment: The OP asked about a textarea, your form has no textarea in it. How is this an answer to the question?