# Rails 3 form actions and methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have made a resource.

```
resources :dashboards
```

I have a partial file which contains a form and I want to use this partial (as the form elements won't change) to update and create. So here is what I have:

**Controller**

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
 def new     
    @dashboard = Dashboard.new
  end
end
```

**View**

/dashboards/new.html.erb

```
<%= render :partial => "form", :locals => { :dashboard => @dashboard } %>
```

**Partial Form**

/dashboards/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@dashboard) do |form| %>
.....
<% end %>
```

**Ruby Guide**

The Ruby Guide states:

The Article model is directly available to users of the application, so — following the best practices for developing with Rails — you should declare it a resource. When dealing with RESTful resources, calls to form_for can get significantly easier if you rely on record identification. **In short, you can just pass the model instance and have Rails figure out model name and the rest.** For example:

```
## Creating a new article
# long-style:
form_for(@article, :url => articles_path)
# same thing, short-style (record identification gets used):
form_for(@article)

## Editing an existing article
# long-style:
form_for(@article, :url => article_path(@article), :html => { :method => "put" })
# short-style:
form_for(@article)
```

**Result**

I thought I have followed the Rails Guide correctly. Because I made @dashboard a resource. I could just pass it into the form and have it handle the action, method and the rest. Instead I'm getting this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/dashboards" class="new_dashboard" id="new_dashboard_" method="post">
```

According to the docs. Shouldn't the action of my form now be "/dashboards/new" because we are on the new action? And should it be passing an extra field declaring the method to be put when I use the same code in the /edit action??

My result is always the same no matter what. The form never changes.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Here is my router info from `rake routes`

```
GET    /dashboards(.:format)          dashboards#index
POST   /dashboards(.:format)          dashboards#create
GET    /dashboards/new(.:format)      dashboards#new
GET    /dashboards/:id/edit(.:format) dashboards#edit
GET    /dashboards/:id(.:format)      dashboards#show
PUT    /dashboards/:id(.:format)      dashboards#update
DELETE /dashboards/:id(.:format)      dashboards#destroy
```

Comment: Ok I got the form action to change to the current controller. I was passing `@dashboard` in the `form_for` instead of `:dashboard`. But now when I'm on the /new action in the controller shouldn't the form action be /dashboards/create not /dashboards/new?

Comment: And the method isn't set in the form either like the guide said it would if I did an update by going to /dashboard/:id/edit

Comment: If you change it to `:dashboard` then you will switch to using the [form tag helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html) instead of the (resource-oriented) [form helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html). The difference is confusing, see this answer for more on the distinction between the two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537700/textarea-in-rails-form#13537848

Comment: What you had originally was mostly correct, but I would switch `@dashboard` to `dashboard`: `form_for(dashboard)`, since you are passing in the instance using `:locals => { :dashboard => @dashboard }`.

Comment: Ahh @shioyama you are correct. That solved it. Cheers!

Comment: No problem! The form helpers can be a bit confusing at first, but once you get used to them they are very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you should be able to "pass `@dashboard` into the form and have it handle the action, method and the rest." The issue here is what `new` is in the context of RESTful actions.

When you declare a set of resources with `resources :dashboards`, you are creating a set of routes which map requests to controller actions:

```
GET     /dashboards             index
GET     /dashboards/new         new
POST    /dashboards             create
GET     /dashboards/:id         show
GET     /dashboards/:id/edit    edit
PUT     /dashboards/:id         update
DELETE  /dashboards/:id         destroy
```

You can check this if you run `rake routes`.

The issue here is that the `new` action is defined as a `GET` request to the path `/dashboards/new`, i.e. this is the route *for the form itself*. The URL in the `action` attribute of the actual form is something else: this is where the form will post the data to with a `POST` request, which on the server (rails) side will map to the `create` controller action.

When you use the form helper with `form_for(dashboard)`, a form is created with a route corresponding to what `dashboard` is: if it is a new record (i.e. it does not yet exist in the database), then the form action will be `create` (and point to `/dashboards`), whereas if it already exists it will point to the actual URL for the record (e.g. `/dashboards/123`). This is what makes the form helpers so useful.

So, to sum up, `/dashboards` is the correct URL, not for the `new` action but for the `create` action, which the form helper uses because `dashboard` is a new record. `new` is the route to the page where the form resides, i.e. `/dashboards/new`.

Hope that makes sense.

p.s. as a side note, you shouldn't be accessing `@dashboard` in the partial if you are passing it in as a local (`:locals => { :dashboard => @dashboard }`). Just use `dashboard`.

Comment: Hi @shioyama Thanks for your quick answer. Right now when I view http://localhost:3000/dashboards/new the form action is `/dashboards/new' not just '/dashboards'. Posting the form to /dashboards/new obviously doesn't work. I have put my route info in the post edit above.

Comment: Did you change something? Originally it was `/dashboards`, which was correct. You should have `form_for(dashboard)`, not `form_for(:dashboard)`.